# Store values from dynamic, looped query into single field (not php array)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a keyword table that I obtained by querying a specific site's API, the structure is like this:

```
keyword1    value
keyword1    value2
keyword1    value3
keyword1    value4
keyword2    value5
keyword2    value6
```

This continues for 350,000 rows.

I've tried using PHP for & while loops but the best I can get (with my limited experience) is the following:

```
keyword1    {terrible php array dump of correct corresponding values}
keyword2    {terrible php array dump of correct corresponding values}
keyword3    {terrible php array dump of correct corresponding values}
```

I really would like something like this:

```
keyword1    value, value1, value2, value3...
keyword2    valuex, valuex+1 ...
keyword3    valuey, valuey+1 ...
```

Ultimately it's really just pivoting the existing data and storing the columns that match the unique keywords in a single MySQL, comma-delimited field.

My thinking is (I know the syntax is mixed & not correct):

```
$keywords = select distinct original_kw from tbl_keyword;

foreach( $keywords as $keyword) {
    $result = select * from tbl_keyword where original_kw = $keyword
        foreach( $result as $answer){
            update new_tbl_keyword 
                set $original_kw = $keyword 
                set $suggested_kw = groupconcatenate($result,", ",$answer);
        }
}
```

Whether it's best to do it in PHP or a single MySQL script is beyond me, I'm not a developer but I've used this site to get as far as I have & this site is awesome! I have managed to query API, pass authentication headers and interpret JSON all to get this far, now I'm stuck & desperately need help!

Comment: How do you produce `{terrible php array dump of correct corresponding values}` exactly? And how deep is the array? If the max depth is 1, consider using [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: What is `valuex` `valuex+1`? What is the `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your data already in a SQL table you can just write:

```
SELECT keyword, GROUP_CONCAT(value)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY keyword
```

and you'd get:

```
keyword1    value, value1, value2, value3...
keyword2    value5, value6 ...
```

Comment: if you want to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the resulting keywords from this query into another table, consider using `REPLACE INTO ... SELECT FROM ..` sql syntax.